# Adding numbers from 1 to 100 OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to get the sum of numbers from 1 to 100 using only 5 threads even though I have 12 available.

This was my approach.
Please show me where I went wrong.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int nthreads = 5, tid;
int sum = 0;
int a[100];

for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++){
    a[i] = i;
}

  /* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();

#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:sum)

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        sum = sum + a[i + 1];
    }

    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Current thread is %d\n", tid);
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    printf("The total sum is %d\n\n\n", sum);

  }
```

Edit: This is the output I am getting:
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQfVO.png)

The Output that I want is the following:

- The total sum is 5050 instead of 4950
- is there a way to output the each thread's local sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in your code, namely:

First:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++){
    a[i] = i;
}
```

you have allocated the array `a` as `int a[100];`, so in your loop you are getting of the array boundaries, changed it to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    a[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Second:

```
int nthreads = 5
...
/* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
```

this makes no sense. You create a parallel region, all threads have a copy of `nthreads` they set that variable to the number of threads, but after the parallel region that value is gone. The only reason why you print afterwards `5` in:

```
printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
```

is because `nthreads` was initially set to 5.

Third:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        sum = sum + a[i + 1];
    }
```

you are again accessing positions outside the array `a`, change that to:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
```

Fourth:

> I'm trying to get the sum of numbers from 1 to 100 using only 5
> threads even though I have 12 available.

Because you did not specified the number of threads in the parallel region:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:sum)
```

you code is running with 12 threads.

> The Output that I want is the following:
>
> The total sum is 5050 instead of 4950 is there a way to output the
> each thread's local sum?

What you want to do is the following:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sum = 0;
   int a[100];

   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       a[i] = i + 1;
   }
   int total_threads_used;
   // Create a parallel region with 5 threads and reduce the partial sum's values
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(5) reduction (+:sum)
   {
        total_threads_used = omp_get_num_threads(); // Get the total threads used
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
           sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        printf("Current thread is %d and SUM %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), sum);  
    }
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", total_threads_used);
    printf("The total sum is %d\n\n\n", sum);
}
```

Output:

```
Current thread is 0 and SUM 210
Current thread is 2 and SUM 1010
Current thread is 1 and SUM 610
Current thread is 3 and SUM 1410
Current thread is 4 and SUM 1810
Number of threads = 5
The total sum is 5050
```

The lines will be outputted in different orders from run to run, since these lines are being printed in parallel, but regardless of the run you should have 5 `"Current thread is"` from 0 to 4, 1 `"Number of threads = 5"`, and 1 `"The total sum is 4950"`.